# Probability and Percentage

Tags: probability

If there is a 70% chance a ball game will be played on any given day what is the probability of a ball game being played Monday through Friday?

Answer (score 3):

$70\% = \dfrac{70}{100} = 0.70$

---

$$\underbrace{(0.7)}_{M}\cdot \underbrace{(0.70)}_{T} \cdot \underbrace{(0.70)}_{W} \cdot \underbrace{(0.70)}_{R} \cdot\underbrace{(0.70)}_{F} = (0.70)^5$$

Comment: What is the probability in percent form?

Comment: Calculate $(0.7)^5 = 0.16807 \approx 0.168$, then multiply the result by $100\%$: $\;0.168\times 100\% = 16.8\% \approx 17\%$.